# Unable to get the count of values present in a variable in shinyApp

Tags: r, input, shiny, radio-button, dt

I'm building a shinyApp on mtcars data. I'm facing a problem in counting values of **disp variable**. 
When **all** is selected in **carb button**, then *disp* shows *0 count*. If values other than *all* are selected in *carb* then disp will give accurate count of its values.
Can somebody please have a look at my codes. I shall be extremely grateful.

```
library(shiny)   
library(DT)     
library(dplyr) 
library(shinythemes) 
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(shinydashboard)


data_table<-mtcars    

#ui
ui = fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (

      uiOutput("vs_selector"),
      uiOutput("carb_selector"),
      uiOutput("disp_selector"),
      uiOutput("cyl_selector"),
      valueBoxOutput("count_disp"),
      valueBoxOutput("count_cyl")),


    mainPanel(

      DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') 

    )

  ))




#server
server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$vs_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(inputId = "vs",
                label = "vs:", multiple = TRUE,
                choices = c( unique(data_table$vs)),
                selected = c(0,1))

  })

  output$carb_selector <- renderUI({

    req(input$vs)

    available0 <- data_table[c(data_table$vs %in% input$vs ), "carb"]  

    selectInput(
      inputId = "carb", 
      label = "carb:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available0))),
      selected = 'All')

  })


  output$disp_selector <- renderUI({
    req(input$vs, input$carb)

    available <- data_table[["disp"]][data_table$vs %in% input$vs]
    if(! "All" %in% input$carb){
      available <- available[data_table$carb %in% input$carb]
    }

    selectInput(
      inputId = "disp", 
      label = "disp:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = c(160,108, 258, 360))

  })



  output$cyl_selector <- renderUI({
    req(input$vs, input$carb, input$disp)

    available <- data_table[["cyl"]][data_table$vs %in% input$vs]
    if(! "All" %in% input$disp){
      available <- available[data_table$carb %in% input$carb    &    
data_table$disp %in% input$disp]
    }

    selectInput(
      inputId = "cyl", 
      label = "cyl:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character(unique(available))),
      selected = 'All')

  })





  output$count_disp <- renderValueBox({
    if("All" %in% input$carb) {
      available <- unique(data_table[['disp']][data_table$vs %in% input$vs] 
)
    } else{
      available <- unique(data_table[['disp']][data_table$carb %in% 
input$carb   &    
                                          data_table$vs %in% input$vs ]   )                                                        
    }

    valueBox(
      value = length(available) ,


      subtitle = sprintf("Number of disp values" ))   

  })




  output$count_cyl <- renderValueBox({
    if("All" %in% input$disp) {
      available <- unique(data_table[['cyl']][data_table$vs %in% input$vs] )
    } else{
      available <- unique(data_table[['cyl']][data_table$carb %in% 
input$carb   &    
                                                 data_table$vs %in% input$vs  
&    
                                                data_table$disp %in% 
input$disp ]   )                                                        
    }

    valueBox(
      value = length(available) ,


      subtitle = sprintf("Number of cyl values" ))   

  })







  thedata <- reactive({

    req(input$disp, input$vs, input$carb, input$cyl)

    data_table<-data_table[data_table$vs %in% input$vs,]

    if(! "All" %in% input$carb){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$carb %in% input$carb,]
    }

    if(! "All" %in% input$disp){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
    }


    if(! "All" %in% input$cyl){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl,]
    }


    data_table

  })


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable( {     

      thedata()   # Call reactive thedata()

    })

  })

}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  renderValueBox You are trying to subset `data_table[['disp']][data_table$carb %in% input$carb & data_table$vs %in% input$vs]` But `input$carb == "All"`, so your subset returns a numeric with length 0.

Edit based on your first comment. I added a function that returns the unique values for a vector ("cyl", "carb", etc). We can use this function to A populate the selectInput and B to return the length of unique values based o what is selected.

```
library(shiny)   
library(DT)     
library(dplyr) 
library(shinythemes) 
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(shinydashboard)

#Input data
data_table<-mtcars

#Function returning all choices for given selector
ReturnChoices <- function(data, xSelector){
  choices <- unique(data[[xSelector]])
  return(choices)
}

#ui
ui = fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (

      uiOutput("vs_selector"),
      uiOutput("carb_selector"),
      uiOutput("disp_selector"),
      uiOutput("cyl_selector"),
      valueBoxOutput("count_disp"),
      valueBoxOutput("count_cyl")),


    mainPanel(

      DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') 

    )

  ))




#server
server = function(input, output, session) {


  output$vs_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(inputId = "vs",
                label = "vs:", multiple = TRUE,
                choices = c( ReturnChoices(data_table, "vs")),
                selected = c(0,1))

  })

  output$carb_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(
      inputId = "carb", 
      label = "carb:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character( ReturnChoices(data_table, "carb"))),
      selected = 'All')

  })

  output$disp_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(
      inputId = "disp", 
      label = "disp:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character( ReturnChoices(data_table, "disp"))),
      selected = c(160,108, 258, 360))

  })

  output$cyl_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(
      inputId = "cyl", 
      label = "cyl:",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c('All',as.character( ReturnChoices(data_table, "cyl"))),
      selected = 'All')

  })

  output$count_disp <- renderValueBox({

    valueBox(
      value = length( ReturnChoices(thedata(), "disp")) ,


      subtitle = sprintf("Number of disp values" ))   

  })


  output$count_cyl <- renderValueBox({

    valueBox(
      value = length( ReturnChoices(thedata(), "cyl")) ,


      subtitle = sprintf("Number of cyl values" ))   

  })

  thedata <- reactive({

    req(input$disp, input$vs, input$carb, input$cyl)

    if(! "All" %in% input$carb){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$carb %in% input$carb,]
    }

    if(! "All" %in% input$disp){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
    }

    if(! "All" %in% input$cyl){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl,]
    }

    data_table<-data_table[data_table$vs %in% input$vs,]

    data_table

  })


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable( {     

      thedata()   # Call reactive thedata()

    })

  })

}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and let me know if it solves it for you

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, really grateful to you. I have added one more filter **cyl** and unable to get the count of values for that, moreover its not showing the choices as well. I updated my codes above. Could you please have a look again?

Comment: Edited the answer, based on your comment. Is this the behaviour you need?

Comment: Hi mate, thanks again, this isn't the required behavior. Because when i select any value from **vs** i should be getting respective values in **carb** and so on. I shouldn't be getting complete values of carb, disp or cyl. Your previous answer was right as showed the choices accordingly